# Is it possible to automatically filter User Configurable Reports or Report Builder reports by Organization?

Tags: commcare

When building a Report using UCR or Report builder, I would like to have it automatically filtered to the Organization that the mobile worker is assigned to. Is this possible?

Comment: I think Ben means "Web user" instead of "Mobile worker".

Comment: Either web user or mobile worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible.

You should set your user's role to not allow data access for all locations.
This will hide all UCR reports for that user that are not "location safe"

[image]

Then, in your UCR, you should add a [location choice provider](https://github.com/dimagi/commcare-hq/tree/master/corehq/apps/userreports#choice-providers). This will automatically scope the data to the user's assigned location, and will allow the user to drill down to data assigned only to locations below the user's assigned location.